# Minimizing an elastic net loss function

Tags: regression, machine-learning, elastic-net

Reading through Andrew Ng's cs229 notes he shows [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiW1ODjovPyAhU1SjABHU4NB1wQFnoECBQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsgfin.github.io%2Ffiles%2Fnotes%2FCS229_Lecture_Notes.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1cLKQwoDwFXlhCYEQa2_oY) on page 10 how you can minimize a loss function $J\left( \theta \right)$ representing the sum of least squares by taking the gradient with respect to the weight $\theta$ to receive the expression $X^{T}X\theta - X^{T}\vec{y}$. My question is, what expression do you receive when minimizing the elastic net loss function $J\left( \theta \right) = \left\| X\theta-\vec{y}\right\|^2 + \lambda_1\left\| \theta\right\|+ \lambda_2\left\| \theta\right\|^2$ in a similar fashion?

Looking online, the best that I found is [this](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/QrMXd/regularized-linear-regression) which near the end gives you a normal equation for $\theta$ if your loss function has ridge regression.

Comment: Do you mean a convenient formula for $\hat\beta_{\text{elastic net}}$  like how ordinary least squares has $\hat \beta_{ols}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty?$

Comment: Yes @Dave, that is correct

Comment: I may have been incorrect about LASSO lacking a closed-form solution. I always thought it lacked one, though, so I’m not sure what I read.